# Cannot change width of input in bootstrap-3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am newbie and trying to learn but I am stuck here. I created following page which is supposed to have an **in-line form** to search for users. It perfectly works when I resize window, except the time that window is full size.

**When the window is in full-size I need the inputs to be a bit wider**, but I could not make them any wider than their default size, although they perfectly get resized when the window is in small size (iPad / tablet and smart phone size)

I followed this [description](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) and wrapped each of them in a separate div to no avail.

**As there were some misunderstanding please note following:**

- The form need to be in-line
- Both search boxes should be a bit wider when the window is in full-size (other window sizes are fine)
- Please click on Demo link below, as you can see when the fiddle is opened (before changing its size) the width of both search boxes are short and should be a bit extended to have more space to type the values.

When I add width: 96%; to the inputs to test, their widths do not change much. I am puzzled with this issue.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: green;">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="logo" style="margin-right: 0px; float: right;">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="40px" height="40px" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="banner">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-32Ge8DaAq_81IBLPFdRWmKVYgvN9YyDKKjXh6CTTpgey8qbC" height="40px;" width="300px;" />
            </div>
               <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="images" style="float: left;">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px" />
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px" />
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px" />
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">..</div>
```

Comment: I actually din't understand. Do you want this https://jsfiddle.net/k4uugehn/embedded/result/? You change the width if you want accordingly

Comment: @TusharGupta thats correct, however, your answer has a minor bug when resize the screen it goes from in-line to vertical and while I am making the window smaller it goes back to in-line and then vertical again. The rest is fine.

Comment: plz check now https://jsfiddle.net/5sj6zdho/embedded/result/

Comment: Your question is so **confusing** !! What do you mean by " window is in full-size " .. Please clear this

Comment: @Junaid if you make the browser as wide as possible then you would see the width of input boxes are short. I need them to be a bit wider. If you resize the window and make the window in a small size (in size of tablet or cell phone) you would see the width of the input boxes are sufficient for that size of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used some random html from my previous project here. You can surely try it.

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2hcnydwf/6/

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 search-container">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 searchbox">
                    <input class="form-control searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Area">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <select class="form-control searchinput">
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <select class="form-control searchinput">
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <button href="#" class="btn-search">Search</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
.searchinput{height: 40px;border:#fff 1px solid;box-shadow: none;}
```

Comment: Alright, please also write such comments in the comment section otherwise people would vote this negative.

Comment: Actually comment requires, 50 reputation which I dont have. Thats why an answer..!!

Comment: I added the code to jfiddle but do not know how to activate bootstrap on it

Comment: Thanks for your comment I figured out how to add it to jfiddle please have a look at it. Because of your valuable suggestion, I  voted you up to get more points :D

Comment: I will get back to you shortly.

Comment: I already used col-md-9 but did not work, I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I added your code to the Jfiddle it does not make any change.

Comment: Thanks but you  got me wrong, I want the form to be in-line thats what is making all the problems.

Comment: Great thanks, but when the window is in full-size the form is not inline anymore. Have a look at my updated fiddle plz

Comment: Hey, If you have just three columns just use col-md-4 instead of col-md-3 thats all.

Comment: Many thanks, the only problem is you changed the button to anchor. It must be a button. (same as my sample code), the other issue is when the window is small the button will become huge, its size should not get changed and should always be at the right side. please help thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update, if you resize the window would see in a specific size the size of the search button would be same as the input boxes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: updated. Have a look now. Just rename the div class to col-md-3 col-sm-6 and col-xs-6 thats all.

Comment: Thanks but same issue exists.

Comment: Sorry have not seen your updated code, it is now visible thanks

Comment: Highly appreciated, it is great, the last question would be how to have the search button on the bottom right corner when the window size get smaller (in tablet and cell phone size)?

Comment: You can use :  float:right

Generally what happens is everything gets stacked one below the other when you reduce the size. 
If you use col-sm-6 and col-xs-6 every two input boxes will be placed one beside the other. So your search box automatically moves right. But if you use col-sm-12 and col-xs-12 on all the text boxes, then you can use float:right to make the search box go right.

Comment: I have similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159312/the-elements-are-not-fixed-on-the-window please have a look thanks.