# The elements are not fixed on the window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On the header, I need to have

- the logo be located the left side of the banner (without space)
- Both banner and logo be always in the middle of the page (regardless of screen size)
- Also have four images that should always be on the top right side of
  the window (regardless of screen size)

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/b9tbxtLb/10/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .form-control{
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
     -moz-border-radius: 5;
          border-radius: 5;
}

#logo{
        float:right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #logo{
        float:left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo{
        float:left;
    }
}



.searchinput{
  height: 40px;
  border:#000 1px solid;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.btn-search{
  background: #777;
  width:95%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:8px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.btn-search:hover{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #3c3c3c;
  background: #3c3c3c;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-search:a{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-2">
<div id="banner">
<div id="logo" style="margin-right:0px;">
<img height="40px" width="40px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA">
</div>
  <img height="40px;" width="300px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-32Ge8DaAq_81IBLPFdRWmKVYgvN9YyDKKjXh6CTTpgey8qbC"></div>
</div>


</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div id="images" style="float:right;">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

### Update

So far, I could put the images on the top right of the window.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-2">
<div id="banner">
<div id="logo" style="margin-right:0px;">
<img height="40px" width="40px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA">
</div>
  <img height="40px;" width="300px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-32Ge8DaAq_81IBLPFdRWmKVYgvN9YyDKKjXh6CTTpgey8qbC"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-10">
<div id="images" style="float:right; position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 9999;">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: remove `margin-left: 50%`

Comment: @ProfileTwist I added that to have them in the middle of the page.

Comment: My comment answered your original question: `I have a logo that need to be stick to the left side of the banner, also four images that should always be on the top right side of the window but none of the work.`. I am not going to help you if you change your question when the solution is given.

Comment: @ProfileTwist I am updating the question.

Comment: @ProfileTwist question is updated and you promised me to help :)

Comment: I am not good in taking guesses what are the negative votes for ?

Comment: dude can you please try to solve it on your own? you got so many approaches, simply adjust it to your needs man...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to your needs. if you do it like this you don't even need a media query!

Please pay attention to the new added class `google` for the google image and the removed `width` property

http://jsfiddle.net/b9tbxtLb/16/

```
#logo{
    display: inline-block;
}

.google {
    display: inline-block;
}
#banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#images img{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {}
```

although i think you would be able to solve it on your own, with so many approaches provided ;)

Comment: I changed the styles to following and it perfectly work now, thanks <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-5">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-7">

Answer (score 3):

**you misplaced one div**

you no wrong in one div that you forgot to put it try to check in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .form-control{
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
     -moz-border-radius: 5;
          border-radius: 5;
}

#logo{
        float:right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #logo{
        float:left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo{
        float:left;
    }
}



.searchinput{
  height: 40px;
  border:#000 1px solid;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.btn-search{
  background: #777;
  width:95%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:8px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.btn-search:hover{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #3c3c3c;
  background: #3c3c3c;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-search:a{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="background-color:orange;">
<div class="col-md-9">
<div id="banner" style="margin-left: 49%;">
  <img height="40px" width="40px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA">
  <img height="40px;" width="300px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-32Ge8DaAq_81IBLPFdRWmKVYgvN9YyDKKjXh6CTTpgey8qbC">

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div id="images" style="float:right;">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA" width="20px" height="20px"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if just a div is misplaced, please wrote that as a comment, answer section is to be used for the actual answers to the question; however, the code you posted is not an answer to my question. thanks

Comment: so the real question as to what and what his problem

Comment: It is great thanks, but the issue is as I asked in the question the logo should be stick to the banner. In the output of your code, the logo sticks to the left side of the window not to the banner.(in the middle of the page), thanks in advance.

Comment: check my snippets jack :)

Comment: thanks but it has some bugs. when you make the window smaller (tablet / phone size) the images are not on the top right corner and the positions of logo and banner are not correct ( they wont stay in the middle of the page) the right side of the banner is out of the window. I am also working on it lets see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem can be solved by adding sm and sx

Comment: the question is now on bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

how about [centering inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/Paul_Kozlovitch/pbv7t04v/1/)?

```
#banner-container {
    text-align: center;
}

#banner {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: the problem is logo and the banner wont be responsive then, if you resize the window in your example would see the size of banner and logo wont change.

Comment: You said nothing about responsiveness in your question, and you own demo isn't responsive. If you want to get help, specify your question.

Comment: As I included @media screen in the styles I thought it would be obvious that it should be responsive. Moreover, twitter-bootstrap is based on mobile friendly design.

Comment: I can't see from your styles what you are trying to achieve. If you could specify what do you understand by 'responsiveness' in your case and what do you want to have as a result you'd probably get more help and less down-votes.

Comment: By responsiveness, I mean the layout of the page should change based on size of screen. Thats why I have media tags to detect the size of screen and adjust the layout. I already added my code and a demo in the question. I do not really get which part is unclear to elaborate further. All I want is to keep the logo and the banner next to each other while changing the size of the window. I already explained it in bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the css which is not required and use only below snippets,
refer to the link below [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b9tbxtLb/12/).

```
#image {
 float: right;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 5px;
 max-width: 20%;
}

#logo {
 margin-left: 10%;
 float: left !important;
 max-width :60%
}
```

and it will solve your issue if you remove the unwanted divs in the HTML part

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that the four images on the right corner of the window should be always on the right side of it as demonstrated in my demo.

Comment: If you see it they will be in right-side only and images resize according to screen-width